# Home page not displaying after successful installation of IBM HTTP server

Tags: apache, http, ibmhttpserver

I have installed IBM HTTP on a Red Hat Linux server . The installation was successful but I was not able to view the home page . Whenever I tried to view the home page , it always displayed ' Forbidden ' message like ' You don't have permission to access / on this server. ' On checking the logs , it showed an error the following error message ----

[Fri May 11 03:18:34.955151 2018] [core:error] [pid 23748:tid 140394669549312] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.16.100.25:56320] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/root/IHS') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Can anybody help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't install to /root since it is normally not readable/executable by non-root users such as the webserver processes that handle requests.  Reinstall in e.g. /opt.

Apache-based servers like IHS generally start as root then transition to a lower-privileged users to handle requests -- like "nobody" or "www-data".

Apache requires not just read access to the file being served and execute access to the document root, but read and execute access to EVERY directory between the root of the filesystem and the document root.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . You are right . The permission was not present in '/root ' because of which I was not able to see the welcome page . I checked the other locations of the path but did'nt checked the permissions for /root . ' nobody ' user comes in ' others ' category & /root did'nt had execute permissions for ' others ' category . However , I have provided the permissions now and the issue is solved.